# Wordpress Custom Post Type categroies

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type called STORIES.
When a user adds a new STORY, I need them to be able to assign a category (or multiple categories) to the post so I can sort them later by category.

To do this, I only want specific categories I assign to the STORY posts to show - NOT all of the wordpress categories attached to every post type.

For example the default Wordpress category is 'Uncategorized'. How do I remove this category (and any othersI don't want) to ONLY show the ones I select via the custom post type editor?

Is there any way I can make this happen?

I am using custom Post Types UI with Advanced Custom Fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with Post Types UI,  You will need to create a new taxonomy. 
Here is the screenshot explaining that
https://s.w.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/screenshot-4.png?r=1180724

Just fill the text boxes with appropriate names, and check STORY under 
"Attach to Post Type" option.

After that you will have custom taxonomy like "Story Category" to use for stories only.